# classic asp xml receiver page doesn't receive the xml (or so it seems)

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on Classic ASP and was going through a possible solution of posting and reading an xml. 
I read Tim's reply (which is pasted below) but this doesn't work for me. It seems xmlDoc.load(Request) doesn't load anything. What could be wrong here? I would very much appreciate a prompt response.

This is the posting page:

```
url = "www.receivingwebsite.com\asp\receivingwebpage.asp"
information = "<Send><UserName>Colt</UserName><PassWord>Taylor</PassWord><Data>100</Data></Send>"
Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", url, false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml" 
xmlhttp.send information
```

This is the receiving page:

```
Dim xmlDoc
Dim userName
set xmlDoc=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.load(Request)
userName = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("UserName").firstChild.nodeValue
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Dim objXmlRequest
Set objXmlRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDOCUMENT.3.0")
  objXmlRequest.async = False
  objXmlRequest.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
  objXmlRequest.validateOnParse = True
  objXmlRequest.preserveWhiteSpace = False

IF objXmlRequest.Load (Request) THEN
  ''' GET THE REQUEST FROM CLIENT
  strQuery = "//" & "ActionName"
  Set oNode = objXmlRequest.selectSingleNode(strQuery)
  strActionName = oNode.Text
END IF
```

' The key is in the property set ... check ".setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True"

Bye, Martin.